# Using Composer with PHP global include path

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

I was using Zend's autoloader before meeting with Composer.

I have got a library (let's call it LibEx) which is in PHP's global include path (`c:\xampp\php\pear`). It must be in a global include folder because a lot of project uses it. So, if I change a function in LibEx every project can access the latest version.

And if I want to push my code to server, I simply copy my LibEx folder to `library` folder which is autoloadable by Zend. Before Composer I was using this method:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library/Zend'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

include "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('LibEx');
```

Now I'm in love with Composer. It's really fantastic and I can autoload my project specific library with it too:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"MyLib": "src/"}
}
```

But how can I autoload LibEx folder which is not in the DocumentRoot or WebRoot? And how to still autoload even if it's in server and copied under `src` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"MyLib": "c:\somewhere\project\src"}
}
```

On Linux soft linking folders would be a possible solution, I don't know if Windows do support it this days or not.

Comment: Sure it works but should i do "php composer.phar update" after i copy LibEx to src folder for production?

Comment: Another way if LibEx is PSR-0 compatible is to do: `$loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; $loader->add('LibEx', '/path/to/libex');`

Comment: @cnkt I dont understand your question :(

Comment: Well, i solved it the hard way. Thanks anyway, i'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add :

```
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
```

to your composer.json, this will take into account paths defined in global php configuration, and you don't have to hardcode the full path.